# Complexity of walking through a layer tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree, time-complexity

I have a layer tree that looks like this
[image]

Layer one tree is a balanced binary search tree that stores some data(say integers) in an specific order, Each node v of the layer 1 tree contains a pointer to the root of a balanced binary search tree, called a layer 2 tree, storing the points of Sv1( sub tree of v )at its leaves.

Now there is an update function that takes an input like p and acts like this:

> Search for p in layer one tree, for each node v on the search path search for p in layer two, let Lv be the leaf of this layer two tree in which the search ends. Then starting at Lv walk back to the root of layer two tree of v and for each node on the path recompute its value.

My book says that this action can be performed in lg^2(n) (n is the number of nodes in layer one tree). But I don't understand how. Here is the algorithm that I have written for this task:

```
L1Search(LayerOneNode* n){
    if (n == NULL) return;
    if (n->data < p)
        L1search(n->left);
    if (n->data > p)
        L1search(n->right);
    L2Search(n->pointerToLayerTwoRoot); //For each node on the search path
}
L2Search(LayerTwoNode* n){// Start at the leafs of the Layer-Two tree and go up
    if (n == NULL) return;
    L2search(n->left);
    L2search(n->right);
    computeTheValueForThisNode();
}
```

Im not sure but I thing the complexity of my algorithm is n*lg(n) not lg^2(n). Am I right? is there any better algorithms to perform this task?

Answer (score 1):

While searching in the layer 1 tree you iterate through `height(tree)` nodes at max. The height of the balanced binary tree is `lg(n)` (with `lg` being a base 2 logarithm). For each of these `lg(n)` nodes you basically repeat the search in another tree with the number of elements <=n (since it is a subtree). This search again costs you `lg(n)`. Since you do the second search (which costs `lg(n)`) for each of `lg(n)` elements of the first search path the resulting complexity is a multiplication `lg(n)*lg(n)`.

Comment: At the second part I do not search for an element, I have to iterate the whole second layer tree, so I don't think that the second part can be performed in lg(n)

Comment: Ahh, I got it now: yes, your implementation is n*ln(n) indeed, but the task is actually different: you should go upwards in the second layer tree, from the leaf Lv to the subtree root, which costs ln(n).